# Porting large code - argument complaints

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am porting a large code to gfortran.  This code was Fortran 77 compliant, very portable, and has run with many different compilers. I'd like to get it running first with minimal changes, then start cleaning it up. I first ran it through f2f90.

So far, I have two major problems, because I have hundreds of calls like these:

1. I have my own second function that mimics the Cray function. Compiler gives error for lines like:

   `CPTSUM = CPTSUM + SECOND(CPT2) - CPT1`

I believe the compiler is checking against its own second function which cannot be called as a function with one argument. How do I get it to look at mine instead?

2. I have a general routine, which can take either a single integer or an array of integers depending on the specific situation. Many calls look like this:

   `CALL IERR(444,NERR,NDUM,' ')`

The subroutine dimensions the 3rd argument as `(*)`. In this example the message needs no integers or text, so `NDUM` is just a dummy scalar integer. The compiler warns me about passing a scalar. `-w` gets around this problem, but may deactivate other warnings.  How do I get it to ignore this one issue? This was an expedient, since Fortran 77 has no optional arguments and most (all other?) compilers don't look at this. One solution is to move the function to a different file, but that will be a PITA.

Comment: Going further along, I find numerous calls like:  CALL SUB1(A,B,DUM1,DUM2,X,Y)  where there are arguments not needed for the particular call.

Comment: With the examples you give there really isn't enough information for us to consider in depth.  Could you add more detail?  You also say the code is F77 compliant: if that's the case I'd expect gfortran to have no problems at all compiling the code (except perhaps around certain deleted features).

Comment: Oh: I misread your "second function".  You mean, you provide a function called `second`.  In which case, try adding the `external` attribute to it.

Comment: Show the code! If we could get a dollar for every code which is supposed to be F77 compliant and is not...

Comment: What are you trying to port it *to*?

Comment: *"One solution is to move the function to a different file, but that will be a PITA."*  This really seems to be the simplest solution if the routine interface is implicit (as common in F77); is this so "PITA" ? (because of too many similar functions with scalar vs array mismatch?)

Comment: I have gotten this code running. There were no errors due to f2f90 other than it choked on most of the include files (usually common blocks). This is a subset split from of a larger code I had already converted.  It ran through f2f90 and then Lahey lf90 with few problems, but I guarantee it will not run with GFortan. I hate editing with the old fixed format, so I usually use this conversion procedure.  I’ve run similar code in F77 and converted to F90 on Lahey, Apple, IBM XLF, HP, SGI, Sun (NAG), etc. Gfortran seems to be a bit quirky, since these problems never cropped up before.

Comment: The "second" function problem was a compile time name conflict. I ended up changing the name and all the gazzilon calls. I don’t know if EXTERNAL would have worked.  Either way involves a lot of changes.

Comment: The second problem mentioned was a warning, but lots of them. When the call looks like the one I mentioned and the subroutine looked like:
SUBROUTINE SUB1(A,B,D,E,X,Y)
DIMENSION A(*),B(*),C(*),D(*),E(*),X(*),Y(*)
The compiler only catches this when both the call and the subroutine are in the same file. I was hoping I could turn off that warning without turning them all off. I ended up compiling it first without –w, then after looking over the warnings, I compiled again –w to insure I hadn’t overlooked any errors.

Comment: The 3rd problem I encountered was a bit more involved. I’m sure you purists will cringe. The code does some c-like memory management with only two nonstandard function calls (to LOC and MALLOC). It’s not worth going into the details, other than there are references to something like AAPNTR(IPNTR).  This is actually a perfectly safe memory area, but Gfortran says it’s out of bounds. Other compilers find this only when subscript range checking is turned on.  To get it running I dimensioned one large array. It shouldn’t be too difficult to change this to a module holding an allocatable array.

Comment: Just to be clear about the second problem in the original post (asterisks somehow disappeared).  The call and subroutine looked like:
`CALL SUB1(A,B,DUM1,DUM2,X,Y)`
and
`SUBROUTINE SUB1(A,B,D,E,X,Y)
DIMENSION A(*),B(*),C(*),D(*),E(*),X(*),Y(*)`
DUM1 and DUM2 are scalars, but C and D are not used in this particular call. Trying to do this with back ticks.